# Import Data Excel Sheet to Multiple Tables in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, import, sql-server-2008-r2

Question: I have a excel sheet in which is contains the below data, I need to import on my Database tables.

```
Category SubCat1 subcat2 Productno      Size    Type    Material               Amount
  a        b       c      100           10mm     K       XYZ/10                  0 
  a        b       c      101           15mm     J       XYZ/11                  12
  a        b       d      102           1mm      N       XYZ/85                  89
  a        b       d      103           3mm      M       XYZ/74                  34
  a        b       e      104           6mm      R       XYZ/10                  43
```

Example:

Example:
List of tables Import needs to be affect:- Category  ,WD_Category  ,Products  ,ProductAttributes  ,WD_ProductsCategory.

Category:- table contains catid and categoryname

WD_Category:- Catid, Parentid – need to set the relationship

Relationship:- Category & WD_Category – CatId & ParentId – Subcat2 parentid is subcat1 and subcat1 parentid is Category but in category table it use to insert like identity wise but in WD_category I’m setting the relationship.

Products: – Productno needs to insert on this table at the same time I’ll get the productid with the help of identity_insert.

ProductAttributes :- with the reference of Productid I suppose to insert the attributenames on this table ProductAttributes .

WD_ProductsCategory:- Combining the tables Ws_category last level(subcat2) and productid in product table using this I’m going to publish the data.

When I’m moving to select productno I suppose to get the entire attributes & categories.
Category,Subcat1,Subcat2 values are located in Category table and the relationship like subcat2 parent is subcat1 and subcat1 parent is Category the relation is like that. And the values reference like catid for category and parentid for parent of subcategory
Productno needs to import on product table and Descript and other attributes need to import on productattributes table.

So from the Excel sheet to I need to import for multiple tables.

Kindly help regarding this import dear friends.